# While loop in stored procedure in sql returns only one row to grid view in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, gridview, while-loop

Using while loop in stored procedure works correctly in SQL server but returns only first row to asp.net grid view.

My stored procedure

```
create procedure [dbo].[DoorDetails] 
@emp varchar(16),
@fromdate datetime,
@todate datetime,
@cdate datetime =@fromdate
as
while @cdate<= @todate
Begin
    select convert(varchar,(CONVERT(date,@cdate,103)),103) as Date, Empname, min(TransactionDateTime) as EntryTime ,max(TransactionDateTime) as ExitTime, 
    (DateDIFF (MINUTE,min(TransactionDateTime), max(TransactionDateTime)))/60 as Hours, 
    (DateDIFF (MINUTE,min(TransactionDateTime), max(TransactionDateTime)))%60 as minutes from 
    ceptEmpTxn where  EmpName = @emp and cast(TransactionDateTime as Date)=cast(@cdate as date)  group by  empname
    SET @cdate = DATEADD(dd,1,@cdate)

end 

GO
```

Result in SQL

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Date|          |Empname|       |EntryTime|              |ExitTime|           |Hours|   minutes|
|14/09/2016|    |PRAVEEN KUMAR| |2016-09-14 09:28:13.000||2016-09-14 18:42:14.000   9   14

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Date|          |Empname|       |EntryTime|              |ExitTime|           |Hours|   minutes|

|15/09/2016|    |PRAVEEN KUMAR| |2016-09-15 09:27:13.000||2016-09-15 17:16:46.000   7   49

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Date|          |Empname|       |EntryTime|              |ExitTime|           |Hours|   minutes|
|16/09/2016|    |PRAVEEN KUMAR| |2016-09-16 09:30:33.000||2016-09-16 19:03:14.000   9   33
```

Headers are repeating each time in sql

Result in Webpage (using Grid view)

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date|       Empname|        EntryTime|              ExitTime|            Hours| minutes|
15/09/2016| PRAVEEN KUMAR|  15-09-2016 09:27:07|    15-09-2016 17:16:46|    7|      49|
```

My function in asp.net

```
 public DataTable tottime(string empname, DateTime fromdate, DateTime todate)
{
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection myConn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ceptConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString());
    DataTable myDt = new DataTable();
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand myCmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
    myCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();
    myCmd.CommandText = "DoorDetails";
    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp", empname);
    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromdate", fromdate);
    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@todate", todate);
    da.SelectCommand = myCmd;
    try
    {
        myCmd.Connection = myConn;
        da.Fill(myDt);
        return myDt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        myDt = null;
        da.Dispose();
        myCmd.Dispose();
        myConn.Close();
        myConn.Dispose();
    }

}
```

How to return all the values from stored procedure also how to have table header only once followed by all the rows.

Comment: Were you able to use the SP below?

Comment: yes stored procedure is working fine. Query gives required output in SQL server but expected result not obtained in grid view.

Comment: In SQL Server are you able to get it as a single result set? instead of grids?

Comment: @balaji no still not able to get in SQL server also

Comment: @balaji working bro thank you :)

Comment: Glad that it worked bro...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you may have to create a table variable and store the result set there and again fetch that result set at the end. Try this.

P.S Please change the data types of table variable (@t) columns accordingly. So that there will not be any troubles.

```
create procedure [dbo].[DoorDetails] 
@emp varchar(16),
@fromdate datetime,
@todate datetime,
@cdate datetime =@fromdate
as
while @cdate<= @todate
Begin
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    [Date] Date
    ,Empname VARCHAR(200)
    ,EntryTime DATETIME
    ,ExitTime DATETIME
    ,[Hours] INT
    ,[minutes] INT
)

INSERT INTO @T 
    select convert(varchar,(CONVERT(date,@cdate,103)),103) as Date
    , Empname, min(TransactionDateTime) as EntryTime 
    ,max(TransactionDateTime) as ExitTime
    ,(DateDIFF (MINUTE,min(TransactionDateTime), max(TransactionDateTime)))/60 as Hours
    ,(DateDIFF (MINUTE,min(TransactionDateTime), max(TransactionDateTime)))%60 as minutes 
    from 
    ceptEmpTxn where  EmpName = @emp and cast(TransactionDateTime as Date)=cast(@cdate as date)  group by  empname

    SET @cdate = DATEADD(dd,1,@cdate)

end 
SELECT * FROM @T

GO
```

Comment: should we declare the table inside while loop? its showing some conversion errors i am just trying it out

Comment: Yes, you have to declare it inside the loop, that conversion errors may be because of inappropriate data types in the @t table. Change them accordingly

Comment: just [Date] should be in char(10) datataype and its working fine both in SQL server and Gridview